# Indentation error in python random numbers game

Tags: python, indentation

This is a simple little guessing game that i've edited. I know that it **should** run fine, but it keeps giving me an error. On line 12 it says "unindent does not match any outer indentation level" with an arrow pointing to the closing parenthesis in "guess = input()". Any help? I can't see what's wrong with it!

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

guessesTaken = 0
print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()
number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
      print('Take a guess.')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + '         guesses!')
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: run it with `python -tt my_script`  never mix tabs and spaces and use a good editor/ide

Comment: Well that's most likely my problem there. I have no choice but to use online IDE's and it messes my code up sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean you have no choice? You can write python in Notepad if you want.

Comment: also there are decent online ide's like ideone,github gist, and several others

Comment: @thegrinner I unfortunately don't have Notepad. I'm using this shitty ass Chromebook. If I had a Windows laptop i'd probably be using Eclipse for coding in Python. Or hell, even IDLE would be better than these crappy online IDE's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
while guessesTaken < 6:
      print('Take a guess.')
    guess = input()
    # the rest of the code
```

The line with `print('Take a guess.')` should have [4 spaces indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). Like so..

```
while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = input()
    # the rest of the code
```

Comment: @Xiam Use `raw_input( )` instead of `input( )` because in Python 2.7 `input( )` actually evaluate the input as Python code, not String. I suggest you stick with `raw_input( )`. `raw_input( )` returns a string and you also can cast it your preferred type (Eg. `int( )`). However, if you are using `input( )` in Python 3.x, it will work just fine.

Comment: @Xiam So to fix this problem, change myName = `input()` to `myName = raw_input()`. I also noticed that you didn't initialize the value `guessesTaken`. I guess you might want to initialize this `guessesTaken = 0` before you begin the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thanakron Tandavas showed you the path, but the entire code just in case...

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

guessesTaken = 0
myName = raw_input('Hello! What is your name?\n')
number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + '         guesses!')
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Notice I used raw_input() instead of input(), 'coz I use 2.7.3 :) Cheers!

Comment: you know you can do `x=raw_input("Take A Guess:")` and dont need an extra line for the prompt right?

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to enter the name in the next line :)